# Usage of product photos on commercial website

Tags: copyright, photo

We are finishing a web-site for a bar that will have photos of drinking products like a can of Coca Cola, a bottle of Red Label, etc, since they are the products commercialized by the website owner at it's own bar.

Can these photos be published or do we need to contact each brand and ask for permission?

**Note:**
Some photos were taken on the bar, others collected using a search engine and others came from a stock photos website.

Comment: Pretty darn sure that falls under fair use

Comment: @JohnConde As per my understanding of "fair use", we can then use these type of images without further concerns. By any chance do you have a link to an "official" documentation on this subject ?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) sums it up nicely. Basically its normal to see their stuff in a bar. As long as you aren't trying to directly capitalize on their trademark, etc, it's ok to use.

Comment: `others collected using a search engine` trademarking issue wouldn't be an issue as John said about fair usage, however the majority of images found on Google search are copyrighted. If concerned you should hire a photographer, use stock images or creative commons images that can be found on Flickr and many other image sites.

Comment: @bybe Thank you for the extra insight, it is a pertinent issue... while I'm still a bit confused about the usage of a picture with a white background and a can of Coca Cola centered, since they're pretty much the same all around the world. We do take care on not using elaborate images like a can sweating from being so cold as if just removed from the fridge. We also avoid search results that lead to images where the privacy policy of the website clearly states that they cannot be used without permission.

Comment: @bybe Don't know if all of this is enough or if we should just take photos ourselves for every product that we can't find on stock photos websites or creative commons images.

Comment: The image regardless of whats in the image can be copyrighted. Your not infringing a trademark by displaying a image of the original item, the problem your face is a copyright issue. Most businesses will use stock images or hire a photographer.

Comment: There are sometimes limits in how a product can be displayed or used within marketing or other works. These limits can be found on most product websites, however, if you were to call their marketing department, I know they have the information handy for you. Having said that, I would not worry about limits if you are using an image or video within the normal constraints of day to day serving and enjoyment and do not promote secondary concerns such as "getting drunk" hence the "please enjoy responsibly" notices. Just be cool- and don't give then a reason to be upset. That is my point.